# Knowing when to use Green/Stokes/Divergence theorem to evaluate line/surface integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\newcommand{\mbf}{\mathbf}$
Evaluate 
$$
\iint \limits_{S} \mbf{F} \cdot d \mbf{S}
$$
where $\mbf{F} = 3xy^2 \mbf{i} + 3x^2y \mbf{j} + z^3 \mbf{k}$ and $S$ is the surface of the unit sphere.

---

I have written my solution below -- is it correct?  Also, how does one know when to use Green/Stokes/Divergence theorem to evaluate a surface/line integral?

---

Note that evaluating this surface integral directly yields an ugly integral of $\int \sin^5(x)\, dx$.  We will resort to Gauss' Divergence Theorem to simplify matters.

Indeed, by Gauss' Divergence Theorem, we have
$$
\iint \limits_{S} \mbf{F} \cdot d \mbf{S} = \iiint \limits_{S_{\text{int}}} (\nabla \cdot \mbf{F}) \, dV.
$$
where $S_{\text{int}}$ denotes the interior of the sphere.
Now, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$.  Now, we are just integrating
$$
\iiint \limits_{S_{\text{int}}} 3(x^2+y^2+z^2) \, dV.
$$
Let's transform this to spherical coordinates.  We obtain the equivalent integral
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} 3 \rho^4 \sin \phi \, d \rho \, d \phi \, d \theta.
$$
$$
= \frac{3}{5} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin \phi \, d \phi \, d \theta
$$
$$
= \frac{12 \pi}{5}.
$$

Comment: Your choice of theorem to apply is correct, but your final simplication of $\nabla\cdot\mathbf F$ is incorrect. Remember that you're integrating over the *inside* of the unit sphere when you do the volume integral.

Comment: You need to integrate $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ over $x^2+y^2+z^2<1$

Comment: Oh, of course, silly error!  I will edit my current solution.

Comment: I have fixed the solution.

Comment: Pay attention when you switch to polar coordinates. You wrote $dV=d\rho d\theta d\phi$, which is wrong.

Comment: Depending on what country you're from, WeierstraßSauce, you might call this spherical coordinates. But, regardless, as @GiuseppeNegro indicated, you need to the correct formula for $dV$, incorporating what I like to call the correct "fudge factor."

Comment: Ah, that's right -- I need to multiply by the magnitude of the Jacobian of the transformation, $\rho^2 \sin \phi$.  I believe I now have a correct solution.